# setfacl permission denied when trying to set acl for mounted network folder

Tags: linux, permissions

I have network folder which mounted on boot by fstab like that:

```
//ip-address/share /share cifs acl,username=guest, password=
```

It's samba folder accesible by all. When i'm working from root it's all fine, but i get Permission denied when i'm trying to get there as user. I tried

```
setfacl -m user:user:rwx share
```

But i got permission denied message for this operation. I tried to umount folder, set acl(went good) and mount again, but when i mounted it acl were gone.
Please advise

Answer (score 0):

Found solution:
To ensure that Samba supports ACLs, set the [share1] configuration in smb.conf to the following:

```
[share1]
   path = /samba/share1
   nt acl support = yes
   writeable = yes
```